# Is it possible to have multiple audiences with clientIds and secrets?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, jwt

With Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt, you could do something like this:

```cs
public static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthConfiguration oAuthConfiguration = OAuthConfiguration.GetConfig("oauth");

    List<string> audiences = new List<string>();
    List<byte[]> secrets = new List<byte[]>();

    foreach (var oAuthAudienceElement in /*configuration*/)
    {
        audiences.Add(/*configuration thingy*/);
        secrets.Add(TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(/*configuration thingy*/));
    }

    // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new List<string>(audiences),
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(oAuthConfiguration.Issuer.Domain, secrets)
            }
        });
}
```

But I am unable to find an equivalent of that in ASP.NET Core 2.X. Is that not supported or am I missing something? I mean, services.AddJwtBearer doesn't provide much:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication("oauth")
    .AddOAuth("oauth", options =>
    {
        // something?
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("oauth", options =>
    {

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // These don't exist as in the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt example above...
            // AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            // AllowedAudiences = new List<string>(audiences),
            // IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            // {
            //     new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(oAuthConfiguration.Issuer.Domain, secrets)
            // }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Well, it's definitely `AddJwtBearer` for accepting Bearer tokens. There is a `ValidAudiences` property on `TokenValidationParameters` for the audiences. You should be able to setup the symmetric signing keys in there as well.

Comment: @juunas I do see that `ValidAudiences` is there. As for the `IssuerSecurityTokenProviders ` from .NET, did you mean that its equivalent in .NET Core is `IssuerSigningKeys`? I mean, one is a "provider" and the other isn't. Sadly, there don't seem to exist many resources for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `AddJwtBearer()` and not `AddOAuth()`.

In `TokenValidationParameters`, audiences, issuers and signing keys can all accept an `IEnumerable` as input, so you can specify multiple values (note that all property names are in plural form):

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidAudiences = new [] {"audience1", "audience2" },
    ValidIssuers = new[] { "issuer1", "issuer2" },
    IssuerSigningKeys = secrets.Select(secret => new SymmetricSecurityKey(secret))
};
```